# How would I get Child's state in parent in initial load itself?

Tags: reactjs, components, state

I have a child component which has initial state amount: "0.00"
During initial load, the parent should also have this state received from child and set it as parents state.

The approach that I was thinking about is during componentDidMount call a function in Parent and pass the value to setState. 
However I was wondering if there is a better way to go about this.
The initial value need to be in child itself first.

```
class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      amountToDisplay: '0.00'
    };
---------

class ChildCard extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      amount: "0.00",
    };
  }
```

During initial load itself I needs to change the amountToDisplay to the initial state of child which is "0.00".

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Parent`, define a function and pass it down as a prop to `Child`. Then in `Child`, call that function in `componentDidMount()`, we can pass in the value from child up to parent like this:

### Parent

```
class Parent extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      amountToDisplay: '0.00'
    };

   setInitialAmount = (amount) => {
      this.setState({
        amountToDisplay: amount
      })
   }

   render(){
      return(
       <ChildCard setInitialAmount={this.setInitialAmount}/>
      )
   }
}
```

### Child

```
class ChildCard extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      amount: "500.00", //or set to any amount you need
    };
  }
   componentDidMount(){
      this.props.setInitialAmount(this.state.amount)
   }
}
```

Comment: That bring to the question should i call the function in child's constructor or componentDidMount? which would be better and why?

Comment: @Jeny, using componentDidMount() to do this type of logic is the standard way of doing it. If another developer were to see your code, they would understand it better. :)

Answer (score 0):

In constructor of child component itself we can call the parent function after set the values to state in child component

Parent

```
class ParentComponent extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      amount: '0'
    };

   getAmount= (amount) => {
      this.setState({
        amount: amount
      })
   }

   render(){
      return(
       <ChildCard getAmount={this.setAmount}/>
      )
   }
}
```

Child Component

```
class ChildComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      amount: "21", 
    };
    this.props.setAmount(this.state.amount)
  }

}
```

Comment: That bring to the question should i call the function in child's constructor or componentDidMount? which would be better and why?

Comment: You can call function in constructor for fast response why means constructor will call first than componentDidMount but standard way is componentDidMount is safe and secure.